# Subnet masking to get 2 subnets each with 126 host

Tags: networking, subnet, ipv4, netmask

Suppose we have a subnet mask of value `255.255.255.128`. May I know please why this would split the network into 2 subnets each with 126 hosts?

From my understanding, if the subnet mask was `255.255.255.0`, it would mean we have 254 host as there is 2 reserved IPs for broadcast (all 0s) and for one for network host (all ones). I am not sure why `255.255.255.128` would give 2 networks each with 126 host.

Comment: Is this a homework question? You need to look at the subnet mask in binary. 128 in the last octet means the 128's place bit is set (the most significant bit of that octet), meaning you have 25 bits of network number and 7 bits for host addresses. 2^7 = 128, minus the all-ones host for broadcast and the all-zeroes "network address", leaving 126 normal unicast host addresses.

Comment: The comment from @Spiff is completely correct. I would add that you should probably read up on IP subnets with documents like [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html). Then play with subnet [calculators](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/). Both of these sites are just examples. I do not endorse these pages above any others that google may suggest to you. CIDR addressing might also help in the understanding. Your example is a /25 network. Looking at /16, /24, or other netmasks will give more understanding of address ranges.

Comment: @Spiff. Thank you. Not HW. But why we would have 2 subnetworks each with 126 hosts? That is my question.

Comment: @Avv A /25 only gives you two subnets if you're using to to subnet (subdivide) a /24. I figured that was implicit in your question. If you use a /25 everywhere across the entire 32-bit IPv4 address space (as if special reservations like multicast didn't exist), it would give you 2^25 (over 33 million) subnets, each with 126 hosts.

Comment: @Spiff. Thanks. I am still not sure how 255.255.255.128 would give 2 networks? Do you mean since 255.255.255.0 and 255.255.255.128 differs by one bit, then since 255.255.255.128 has 128 total addresses, then 255.255.255.0 has 128 addresses left, which is why we have 2 subnetworks? (Copied my comment to user1686)?

Comment: @Avv When you view a subnet mask in binary, everywhere there's a 1 represents the network number, and everywhere there's a 0 represents the host number. So by extending the subnet mask by one bit from a /24 (255.255.255.0 = 11111111.11111111.11111111. **0**0000000) to a /25 (255.255.255.128 = 11111111.11111111.11111111. **1**0000000), now anything that has the most significant bit of the last octet set to 1 is on a different subnet than anything that has that bit set to 0.

Comment: @Avv So if you started with network 192.0.2.0/24 and subnetted it with a /25, you now have two networks: Network 1 is 192.0.2.0/25 (addresses 192.0.2.0 - 192.0.2.127; note that 192.0.2.127 is the broadcast address for the lower subnet) and network 2 is 192.0.2.128/25 (addresses 192.0.2.128 - 192.0.2.255).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, if the subnet mask was 255.255.255.0, it would mean we have 254 host as there is 2 reserved IPs for broadcast (all 0s) and for one for network host (all ones).

Correct, but at this point it's more important that you have *256 addresses,* not that you have 254 hosts.

The all-ones and all-zeros addresses only gain their special meaning at the very end of the process, when the network is actually configured on an interface (and even though they're not available for hosts they're still included as part of the network). But as the original network *won't* be used directly on an interface, the "reserved" discount does not apply to it yet.

So while subnetting, you're not dividing the 254 hosts in half – you're dividing the *whole* 256-address network into two 128-address halves, and only then counting each half as "126 hosts + 2 reserved".

(Also, you got the reserved addresses the wrong way round: All-ones is the modern broadcast address. All-zeros *used to be* the broadcast address in 1980s, now it's called "network address" and is just reserved for legacy reasons.)

> I am not sure why 255.255.255.128 would give 2 networks each with 126 host.

The way a subnet mask works, each '1' bit defines the network part of the address, while each '0' bit defines the host part. For example, your original netmask (255.255.255.0) allows for 256 addresses because it has 8 'host' bits, and those bits can represent 2<sup>8</sup> distinct values.

So if you convert both netmasks to binary, you should see that they differ by one bit (therefore splitting the original network into 2<sup>1</sup> parts), and you should see that the smaller network has 7 "host" bits (therefore giving you 2<sup>7</sup> addresses in total).

Instead of netmasks, these days network sizes are more commonly written in "prefix length" notation, counting the number of '1' bits (e.g. "/24" for 255.255.255.0).

Comment: Thanks. Very clear except for the 2 networks part please. I am still not sure how 255.255.255.128 would give 2 networks? Do you mean since 255.255.255.0 and 255.255.255.128 differs by one bit, then since 255.255.255.128 has 128 total addresses, then 255.255.255.0 has 128 addresses left, which is why we have 2 subnetworks?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can explain it well, but see if https://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html makes it clearer. (Unfortunately it doesn't show the addresses in binary; if you wrote down the netmask and the start-end addresses in binary, it should immediately become clear how they are related.)